# How to concate (Varchar and substract Year from date)?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to update a column in the mainDB table, based on data in the engine table. The date in the main DB table is stored in (YYYY-MM_DD) format and I want to subtract only the year

I'm not sure how to properly join these two tables to update the percentage

```
UPDATE maindb 
JOIN engine ON engine.COL_3 = CONCAT(maindb.COL_1,"-", SUBSTRING_INDEX(maindb.COL_2,"-",-1))                                                                    
SET Maindb.COL_3 = engine.COL_4,
```

[image]

Comment: The third argument `-1` in `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` will return the last field. You want the first field, so it should be just `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the data types of the fields?
There are different solutions for different data types

If **all fields** is `varchar`

```sql
UPDATE maindb m
JOIN engine e ON e.COL_1 = m.COL_1
    AND e.COL_2 = LEFT(m.COL_2, 4)
SET m.COL_3 = e.COL_4
```

If **maindb.COL_2** is `date`

```sql
UPDATE maindb m
JOIN engine e ON e.COL_1 = m.COL_1
    AND e.COL_2 = YEAR(m.COL_2)
SET m.COL_3 = e.COL_4
```

Comment: is using AND function faster than CONCAT varchar&subtract year as text?

Comment: @ThavisackVRCHDV 
Less calculations is better, especially with strings

Answer (score 1):

Your join condition is off.  I think you want:

```sql
UPDATE maindb m
INNER JOIN engine e
    ON RIGHT(e.COL_3, 4) = LEFT(m.COL_2, 4)
SET m.COL_3 = e.COL_4;
```

I suspect that `m.COL_2` is text, in which case the above should work.  It should be a date, in which case we should extract the year and then cast to text before comparing to the the other table.

Comment: for column m.COL_2 is the date format.

Comment: The other answer seems to cover this case already.